# How to invalidate the token saved by Android webview after httpAuthHandler proceeds with correct username/password pair?

Tags: android, authentication, webview, basic-authentication, http-authentication

I have an implementation of a webview where I am loading a url using an API *loadUrl(url)*. Server has an authentication check and therefore server sends 401 in response which gets handled by *onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm)*.

WebView is responding with correct implementation for the first 401 response. After this response, WebView stores an authentication token which gets used for subsequent requests.

Is there any way to invalidate that saved token?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to authenticate a *username/password pair* every time the loadUrl tries to connect to a server.

You should use `loadUrl(String url, Map<String, String> additionalHttpHeaders)`. This method accepts a url and additionalHttpHeaders you want to send with the corresponding url.

For example, for the purpose of Basic Authentication a WebView can submit Authorization header using following steps:

1. Create a string of username and password separated by colon (:). For eg., `username:password`.
2. Encode this string using Base64.
3. Add a key/value pair in map where key = "Authorization" and value = `result of step 2`.
4. Submit the the map with url using above mentioned *loadUrl* method.

I am adding the following code for other developers to understand my solution:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    doWebSettings(webView);
    webView.loadUrl(**url you want to load**, getBasicHeader());
}

private void doWebSettings(WebView webView) {
    ***These are example WebSettings**
    final WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
}

private Map getBasicHeader() {
    Map<String, String> additionalHeader = new HashMap();
    additionalHeader.put("Authorization", "Basic "+ getEncodedString());
    return additionalHeader;
}

private String getEncodedString(String username, String password) {
    final String userpass = username+":"+password;
    return Base64.encodeToString(userpass.getBytes(),
            Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

This solution will make sure that every time a url gets loaded a server would check the Additional headers for authentication rather. Therefore, WebView will not send previous authenticated token. If the provided username/password pair is incorrect then HttpAuthHandler#proceed will get called and default behavior will get invoked which is to cancel the request.